# Define local port name

Tags: c#, wcf, port

Is it possible to define the local port name used by a service using WCF?

I am working on two Windows services using the port 8000 & 8001, and I have noticed that the port 8001 used by one of my service is actually resolved in "RbService". How is that? What does "RbService" means?

Here is the view from [CurrPorts](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/cports.html):

[image: CurrPorts view]

I don't understand where this "RbService" comes from, and why my service using the port 8000 doesn't have a local port name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To define port number and description here is what you can do :

Open the file `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\services` in notepad
and add your desired port and service name in the following format

```
servicename portnumber # comments
```

Example

```
pro5srv 1100/tcp # PRO/5 file service
```

To define local port for WCF BaseURI can be modified under host.

Comment: And... I have discovered that the 8001 port was already used by another application. That explains the "RbService" string.